# How can i list all prefabs in Assets directory as prefabs not string?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;

public class Prefabs : MonoBehaviour
{

    List<GameObject> prefabs = new List<GameObject>();

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        var resourcesPath = Application.dataPath;
        var absolutePaths = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(resourcesPath, "*.prefab", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        foreach (var absolutePath in absolutePaths)
        {
            var prefab = Path.GetFileName(absolutePath);
            prefabs.Add(prefab);
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

The problem is that the variable prefab is a string and the list is type GameObject. What i want to get all the prefabs not as strings but as prefabs.

Update:

I moved all the Prefabs to the path Asstes/Resources
But i'm getting 0 prefabs.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;

public class Prefabs : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        var pres = Resources.LoadAll<GameObject>("Assets/Resources/");
    }
}
```

The variable pres is empty.
I want to get all the prefabs in the folder Resources and the subdirectories in Resources.

Comment: Is this for Editor Plugin or standalone build?

Comment: @Programmer I will want to use it later for example to add part of the prefabs to the terrain trees from the script.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new class, which derives from the GameObject class. And in your new class, you can add a string property.

For example:

```
public class MyGameObject : GameObject{

   public MyGameObject() : base(){

       Console.WriteLine("Calls constructor from base class and this!");
   }

   public string MyPath {get; set;}
}
```

And then you can use your class, like this:

```
List<MyGameObject> prefabs = new List<MyGameObject>();
```

---

```
foreach (var absolutePath in absolutePaths)
{
    var prefab = Path.GetFileName(absolutePath);
    prefabs.Add(new MyGameObject(){MyPath = prefab);
}
```

If you want to play with that constellation, look here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Y1KPpU

Comment: `GameObject` is a built-in Unity class - the OP would not be instantiating it with a constructor, and would also not be able to add new fields directly to it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Unity5, take a look at AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath.  https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath.html

...From the linked page:

```
static void ImportExample()
    {
        Texture2D t = (Texture2D)AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath("Assets/Textures/texture.jpg", typeof(Texture2D));
    }
```

There's a pretty good explanation on the page on how to use.  Pay attention to the notes, as things like "only use forward slashes" is pretty important!
Also note that this is in the UnityEditor namespace (which isn't normally included in a build), so you will probably want an `#if` around it.

```
#if (UNITY_EDITOR) 
... your class/code ...
#endif
```